# How can I change the amount of Top Sites in Firefox when I make a new tab?

Tags: firefox

A quick google search didn't give me the answer, I only learned [how to manage the Top Sites](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/new-tab-page-show-hide-and-customize-top-sites).

It might be useful to customize the *Top Sites* feature depending on the size of your screen; either you want less Top Sites; giving you bigger thumbnails or more sites to - well - have more available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to `about:config` and change `browser.newtabpage.rows` and `browser.newtabpage.columns`

Comment: by "changing" you mean adding? I don't have them yet.

Comment: They do exist on the latest nightly, and just checked 18.0.1 and they are there too. What's you Firefox version?

Comment: Waterfox 16.0.1 ;)
Damn it for not having an automatic update feature

Comment: just updated to 18.0.1. Yes - there it is. It doesn't seem to use up the borders on the right and the left side though :/

Comment: `browser.newtabpage.rows` and `browser.newtabpage.columns` preferences do not work anymore.

Comment: @DxTx unfortunately the respective properties are not configurable any more. They are hardcoded.